# Finding out Adobe Experience Manager last restart time

Tags: aem

Could anyone please temme how to know when my AEM Author/Publish instance was last restarted? I know it can be done from logs. But which log and is there any keyword with which I can grep the log?

Comment: curious, did you figure out a different way to do this programmatically ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can rely on logs to find this out. `error.log` and `stdout.log` look promising. You can grep for any of the sling start events from `stdout.log`. Logs from `stdout.log`
during restart:

```
Loading quickstart properties: default
Loading quickstart properties: instance
Quickstart startup at Thu Sep 13 11:54:21 AEST 2018
UpgradeUtil.handleInstallAndUpgrade has mode RESTART
13.09.2018 11:54:21.762 *INFO * [main] Setting sling.home=D:\Tools\aem\author\crx-quickstart (command line)
13.09.2018 11:54:21.772 *INFO * [main] Starting Apache Sling in D:\Tools\aem\author\crx-quickstart
```

---

**Quicker way:**
There is an admin page which will give you last started time OOTB -> `http://<<host>>:<<port>>/system/console/vmstat`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed info.